# SDP solver output (SDPA, CSDP ...)

Tags: optimization

i want to compute a table of SDP-solutions. I create a bash file that calls an SDP-solver (SDPA or CSDP) for different data sets:

```
problem1.dat-s
problem2.dat-s
...
```

Because i want to create a table of numbers, i dont want the whole output like iterations etc. Is there a way to avoid these messages? Or even better, a way to create one solution-set-file of the data sets?

Thanks, dalvo

Answer (score 0):

It's a while now, since this questions was asked, maybe you have found an answer yourself by now. If not, try calling

```
csdp problem1.dat-s problem1.sol > NUL
csdp problem2.dat-s problem2.sol > NUL
...
```

This way you'll get your solutions written to a solution file. With `CSDP` you'll have one vector and two matrices. Reading these files, you can easily create any other set of solutions. The information written to `stdout` are useless, if you're just looking for the solution, since you'll only find the error values and messages and measures of time. So redirecting `stdout` to `NUL` will help you avoid these informations.

I don't know, how this would actually work with `SDPA`, but considering the information found on the man-pages, it should be the same there.

Comment: Another option is to set the printlevel parameter to 0 to suppress csdp output.